# How do I compile this in windows? Chocolately nor gcc seemed to work

Tags: compilation

This project on github appears to be in C, I am new to compiling even with the included makefile on windows, how do I compile it?  I don't see any way to contact the code contributor on github from what I can tell.

https://github.com/314analytics/TAKtick

Thanks!

chocolately, gcc, etc.